# Как сделать кастомный календарь и кастомный список?

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1) Подскажите, как реализовать такую диаграмму, которая бы рабоатла вместе с календарем. Как нарисовать это все.

2) Внизу есть список из radioButton и поверх них зеленная линия вертикальная. Как сделать эту линию в RecyclerView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пожалуй начнем с простой, второй части:

Нижняя часть экрана - это `RecyclerView`. `RadioButton` находиться всегда в одном месте в Item/ячейке/поле этого `RecyclerView`. Тогда, поверх `RecyclerView`, вы проводите прямую: `FrameLayout` шириной в 1 пиксель, нужного цвета таким образом, чтобы он оказался поверх `RadioButtons`. Высоту RecyclerView ставите по контенту, чтобы прямая не уходила в никуда (либо приделываете эту маленькую палочку непосредственно к `RadioButton` в самом `Item`, получается эдакая прямоугольная башенка)

Верхняя часть сложнее. Так или иначе придется копаться в канвасе и писать собственный фрагмент с диаграммой. Вы можете попробовать найти схожую либу с открытым исходным кодом и "позваимствовать" код оттуда (android arsenal вам в помощь). График вы оформляете в виде фрагмента, где месяцы - это `TabLayout` + `ViewPager`.

Как-то так.

Comment: Зачем проводить прямую поверх, если это можно в элементе сделать сверху (или с середины для первого) до низу (до середины последнего)?

Comment: все зависит от дизайна